# Send a PHP variable that has a POST to another PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm doing a page that sends the user's HTML input to PHP through AJAX, but I need that information to open another PHP page after a couple of validations

I've tried to include the file in the other file and using the variable but I get "underfined index user", figures it's because I haven't defined that in the new file.

HTML

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username"><input class="input100" type="text" id="user" name="username" placeholder="username">
<span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
<input class="input100" type="password" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="password">
<span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
</div>

<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
<a class="login100-form-btn" id = "logBtn">
Login
</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#logBtn').click(function(event){ 
    user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    password = document.getElementById("pass").value;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"login.php",
        async: false,
        data: {user:user,password:password},
        success: function(data){
            if(data == 'Administrator'){
                window.location.href='../Main/index.php';
             }
             else if(data == 'Emp'){
                window.location.href='../Main/startemp.html';
             }else{
               alert("username or password invalid");
             }
        }
        });
    });
```

login.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "asdadadas";
$dbname = "dsdvvt";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$user' AND clave='$pass'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$user' AND clave='$pass' AND permisos='Administrador'";
    $result_1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_1);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result_1) > 0){
        echo "Administrator";
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        echo "Emp";
        exit(0);
    }

 } else {
    $msg = "Username or password invalid";
    echo $msg;
 }

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
include '../Login/login.php';
$one = $user;?>
```

I need the information I gathered in login.php to send it to index.php, is there a way I can do this?

Comment: curl is what you are looking for

Comment: @RahulMeshram In which PHP file do I have to use it?

Comment: Why don't you use a `form` tag?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Use prepared statements when interacting with database to prevent sql injection

Comment: @Cray got that pointed out, imma look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to work with session.

Start a session with

```php
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

And assign a variable like this:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = "FlowMafia";
```

Print a session variable like this.

```
echo $_SESSION['user'];
```

For more information read this article:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Comment: I start the session in login.php and print it in index.php? Without include?

Comment: You have to always write session_start() if you want to access any values. Please read the article or do some googling.